# Blender Game Engine python loop issue

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have a python script that moves a sphere around. This is basically the start of a snake game. The problem is that the ball stops moving if the keys aren't constantly held down. What I need is for the ball to keep moving in the last direction given by the keys. I think it has something to do with the fact that the script is restarted and the variables reset each tick...

This is the code I'm using:

```
import bge
U = False
D = False
L = False
R = False
def main():
    global U
    global D
    global L
    global R
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    wKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY]
    sKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY]
    aKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY]
    dKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY]

    if wKey and (D == False): 
        U = True
        D = False
        L = False
        R = False
    elif sKey and (U == False): 
        U = False
        D = True
        L = False
        R = False
    elif aKey and (R == False): 
        U = False
        D = False
        L = True
        R = False
    elif dKey and (L == False): 
        U = False
        D = False
        L = False
        R = True
    if U:
        own.applyMovement([0,0.2,0],True)
    if D:
        own.applyMovement([0,-0.2,0],True)
    if L:
        own.applyMovement([-0.2,0,0],True)
    if R:
        own.applyMovement([0.2,0,0],True)
main()
```

This is a link to the file on my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_5f6jmSaHOUW1wTGVlRXFkVUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest if  you are going to use global variables, then run script as a [module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:/Tutorials/Game_Engine/ScriptMode_vs_ModuleMode), otherwise would need set up Boolean properties on object and use them to keep tabs on U, D, L, R.

[image]

Slight change to code, the controller is automatically passed to the module, which needs to have the .py extension.

```
import bge
U = False
D = False
L = False
R = False
def main(cont):
    global U
    global D
    global L
    global R

    own = cont.owner

    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    wKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY]
    sKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY]
    aKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY]
    dKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY]

    if wKey and (D == False): 
        U = True
        D = False
        L = False
        R = False
    elif sKey and (U == False): 
        U = False
        D = True
        L = False
        R = False
    elif aKey and (R == False): 
        U = False
        D = False
        L = True
        R = False
    elif dKey and (L == False): 
        U = False
        D = False
        L = False
        R = True
    # test print 
    print(U, D, L, R)
    if U:
        own.applyMovement([0,0.2,0],True)
    if D:
        own.applyMovement([0,-0.2,0],True)
    if L:
        own.applyMovement([-0.2,0,0],True)
    if R:
        own.applyMovement([0.2,0,0],True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I used your code and instructions, and it works, but the ball still stops when the keys aren't being pressed. I don't want the ball to be able to stop once it has started moving, only change directions.

Comment: Here is the file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42712 It keeps moving for me.... ???

Comment: Oh... Oops, I accidentally unchecked the always sensor... Never mind! Thanks again for the help!